# Date Range issue in MDX SSAS

Tags: ssas, mdx, ssas-2008, ssas-2012

I have one MDX query.

```
select [Measures].[Measure1] on columns,
[Locations].[Location].[LocationKey] on rows
from [MeasureLocation]
where
(
    {[ServiceDate].[Date].[Date].[01-01-2013] : [ServiceDate].[Date].[Date].[01-01-2014]}
)
```

Here I gave date range between 01-01-2013 to 01-01-2014. So ideally SSAS should give record for this date range only. But the actual result is for 01-01-2013 to 31-01-2014. So, it's including whole month[31-01-2014].

Comment: Check the relationship between `ServiceDate` and the fact to which the measure belongs to in dimensions usage tab. It seems they are connected on `year` and not on `Date`.

Comment: If you browse the ServiceDate.Date hierarchy are the dates in the right order? The range operator (:) won't work as expected if the hierarchy isn't sorted right.

Comment: @GregGalloway yes it's sorted.

Comment: @SouravA I checked the attribute relationship. Date was mapped to Month, so I changed it to Day. But got the same result. Then I removed the relationship at all but again got the same result.

Comment: Weird. Did you process the cube after the change?

Comment: @SouravA yes. re-deployed the cube after making these changes.